# Can't get .env variables to work in React using Contentful

Tags: javascript, reactjs, contentful, dotenv

I am trying to connect to Contentful's API in my react project. If I hardcode the space and access tokens it works fine, but if I try to use a .env file it's not getting the token.

Here's my code:

```
import {createClient} from "contentful";


export const client = () => {
    //console.log(process.env)
    let whatever = createClient({
        space: process.env.REACT_APP_SPACE_ID ,
        accessToken: process.env.REACT_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    });
    return whatever;
};

export const getRecipes = async () => {
    try{
        const entries = await client().getEntries({
            content_type: "recipe",
            select: "fields"
        });
        return entries;
    } catch(error){
        console.log(`error fetch: ${error}`);
        return;
    }
}
```

I've tried various patches but nothing has worked. I have react-scripts installed as well.
I console logged the process.env and it doesn't have the token or space id.
I tried importing dotenv but that created some weird polyfill error that I've never seen before.

Comment: Did you use create-react-app? If so, https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables should cover this. If not, you're going to need to tell you _bundler_ to shim those env vars (for example, if you use webpack, load the .env file in your webpack config js, and then pass them into the [environment plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/). Or if you use esbuild, have a look at [esbuild-envfile-plugin](https://github.com/rw3iss/esbuild-envfile-plugin) etc.)

Comment: I'm not sure what you did, but it worked! Yes I used create-react-app and had looked at those docs, but I needed to go into the webpack.config.js file and add ```new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(['REACT_APP_SPACE_ID', 'REACT_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN']);``` not sure what it does but it works now!

Comment: What do you mean, "not sure what it does": https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/ very clearly tells you what it does. You use the plugin and tell it which vars you need, and _it_ makes sure those get put into the fake `process.env` that gets put into your bundle. (because a client side bundle has no "process", the bundler creates an object with _just_ enough content to make the rest of the code think it's working with a normal process object)

Answer (score 0):

It could be that: your env file is not in the project folder but instead in the src/ folder...just check it once to make sure, it's a very easy mistake that a lot of people make.
Or if you have the client folder inside the server folder which is sometimes needed for deployment it might not be working because of that folder structure as well

Comment: It is in the project folder parallel to the gitignore and package.json